# Adding users to Azure B2C without using a sign-up policy

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am attempting to develop an app with only a sign in policy. To the best of my knowledge the supported methods of creating new users for b2c are using the new user dialog on the users page, and with the graph api. Is this correct? Is there a method I'm missing? Which is the preferred method?

When attempting to create users in the new user dialog, usernames become malformed, eg. username@domain.com becomes username_domain.com#EXT#@domain.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The users created through the portal cannot be used by Azure AD B2C. Azure AD B2C uses the 'signin names' property of the user to sign in. The users created through the portal can be used for sign in using AAD (enterprise scenario).

Azure AD B2C has a sample for creating user accounts using AADGraph, which can be used for creating users in cases where only signin is supported. 
[Create consumer user accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet#create-consumer-user-accounts)