# Azure AD B2C authentication

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I created an Azure AD B2C tenant, added applications to it and configured Postman according to this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/azure-ad-b2c-webapi?view=aspnetcore-2.2

My problem is I can't log in with user accounts which I added to my tenant. 
I created two users the user type of them is member ansd source is Azure Active Directory.
But when I try to log in I get back the following error message:
"Invalid username or password."

What should I set up yet?

Comment: Where are you trying to log in with these credentials?

Comment: To add to @rickvdbosch's question, you must create the new user using either a sign-up policy/flow or using the Azure AD Graph API. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-overview#consumer-user) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The users created through the portal cannot be used by Azure AD B2C. Azure AD B2C uses the 'signin names' property of the user to sign in. The users created through the portal can be used for sign in using AAD (enterprise scenario).

As Chris mentioned, one needs to use a Signup policy or Azure AD Graph flow to create a user for b2c to be able to sign in.

Please see this answer
[Adding users to Azure B2C without using a sign-up policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54091945/adding-users-to-azure-b2c-without-using-a-sign-up-policy/54098360#54098360)